# VSCode TypeScript Intellisense suddenly broken after 1.7 -> 1.6 downgrade

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am facing a weird issue. Since yesterday my setup was working perfectly with a largish rails, react, and typescript project.

This morning, as I opened the editor, VS Code was suddenly broken. I now get error

`[ts] Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided`

in all of my .tsx files. Even more surprisingly, compilation still works without issue.

This seems inline with the warning I am suddenly getting: `Version mismatch! global tsc (2.0.7) != VS Code's language service (2.0.6). Inconsistent compile errors might occur`.

My directory structure is that of a rails project, plus the `react_on_rails` gem. This means that I have a `client` folder with a webpack installation, and inside the `client` folder we find the `tsconfig` file. `tsconfig` contains the following:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 5
},
```

How do I go about debugging something like this?

Comment: VSCode 1.7.1 has just been released again. Can you check it again?

Comment: Unfortunately, it stays broken. I am adding more information to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

For whomever might be interested, the solution was quite trivial.

I was using webpack, so the list of files in `tsconfig.json` was not really needed: after all, webpack goes through the files it finds, matches extensions, and applies its loaders. Indeed, compilation worked correctly.

It appears that (not unreasonably) VS Code uses the files listed in `tsconfig.json` to determine which files will receive intellisense *according to the parameters specified in the `tsconfig.json` file itself*.

The solution was therefore simply to add references to all of my `*.ts` and `*.tsx` files in `tsconfig.json` to restore intellisense to perfection.